# find td text from td click in same tr

Tags: jquery

Why is this not working `$(this).parents("tr").find("td:eq(2)").html()`

I cant seam to get the text "`getthis`" relative to the `td` `tr` that called it

```
<table>

    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>getthis</td>
        <td onclick="$(this).parents("tr").find("td:eq(2)").html()">4</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>getthis</td>
        <td onclick="$(this).parents("tr").find("td:eq(2)").html()">4</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>getthis</td>
        <td onclick="$(this).parents("tr").find("td:eq(2)").html()">4</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>getthis</td>
        <td onclick="$(this).parents("tr").find("td:eq(2)").html()">4</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>   

</table>
```

Comment: please, please, please, put your code in a .JS file and bind it on the fly, and not with lots of repeated inline event handlers...

Comment: The code being executed just returns a string, it doesn't **do** anything with it, so I'm not sure what you expected to happen.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are using double-quotes too much.  When creating a string in line, you are accidentally ending the `onclick` attribute.  Also, `eq` is zero-indexed, so you want `1` instead.

Better (but only because it works):

```
<td onclick="$(this).parents('tr').find('td:eq(1)').html()">4</td>
```

Best:

```
$("table").on("click", "td:nth-child(2)", function(e) {
    $(this).prev().html();  //Get the previous sibling's HTML without inline JS
});
```

Comment: and that quoting issue is (one of the reasons) why you should never use inline event handlers if you can avoid it...

Comment: strictly speaking, your "best" probably isn't.  When applying the exact same handler to multiple elements that are all descendants of another then IMHO "best" would be a single handler on the parent.

Comment: @Alnitak Yeah, probably.  My original point was *don't use inline handlers* but I updated it to incorporate delegation.

Comment: Hey whadda you know - it looks almost just like mine now ;-)  Oh, and BTW, `:nth-child` is preferable to `:eq` because the former is standard CSS3 and therefore works in `node.querySelectorAll`.  The latter is a jQuery extension which forces the user of the Sizzle engine.  See http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

Answer (score 2):

You should replace your repeated inline event handlers (which are error prone, and outmoded) with a single small junk of code in a `<script>` block:

This uses a single "delegated" handler registered on the entire table, but only listening to clicks on the 3rd column:

```
$('table').on('click', 'td:nth-child(3)', function() {
    alert($(this).prev().html());
});
```

[ This code should of course appear in a `$(document).ready()` handler to ensure it doesn't run until after the DOM is loaded].

Answer (score 2):

Your actual problem is that you use the doublequotes for delimiting your onclick, but also in the jQuery. It should be:

```
 onclick="$(this).parents('tr').find('td:eq(1)').html()"
```

But even better: Just use `prev()` [JQuery Doc](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)

```
$(this).parents("tr").find("td:eq(2)").html()
```

would become

```
$(this).prev().html();
```

Alnd put these click-handlers in a separate function ( although it is possible otherwise, you might want to use a class (e.g. `click`)to address the according td):

```
$('table').on('click', 'td.click', function() {
    alert($(this).prev().html());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>getthis</td>
        <td class="clickMe">4</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
$(".clickMe").click(function() {
    alert(this.parentNode.children[1].innerText);
});
</script>
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/sme7c/1

Comment: careful there - childNodes can contain text elements, including any white space.  That's why I just used jQuery instead of pure DOM.

Comment: @Alnitak thanks, I changed it to `children` property to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

Try `closest` instead of `parents`

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with your code.

1. You're using double-quotes in your jQuery code, but haven't escaped them, so you're prematurely ending the attribute, and generating invalid HTML.
2. The jQuery code simply returns a string, but doesn't **do** anything with it, so you shouldn't expect to see anything.
3. Your element indexing may be wrong; elements are indexed from 0, not 1, so `:eq(2)` returns the third element, not the second. Or, to put that another way, your code finds the exact same element that has been clicked on.